# Animated Gif issue on iPhone, iPad

Tags: ios, animated-gif

I am having an issue where my animated `.gif` (created in PhotoShop) transitions are not rolling out correctly on an iPad and iPhone.

Instead of fading to the next frame, the next frame is appearing a yellow object without having the smooth fade to it.

It is animating just not a smooth animation.

Comment: Thanks for editing, does anyone know of a solution for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You may wish to use [imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) to see if it can solve the problem for you. I've just had to deal with a GIF file which has been working without any issue on desktop browsers, but on ios it has been showing strange blue artifacts.

Just run the GIF through the convert function and then try the output file.

```
convert original_file.gif output_file.gif
```

Imagemagick will probably decode the original file before creating a fresh new output, but without including whatever encoding style caused problems in the original.

Comment: This solved the problem for me. I used it from the browser:
 [http://transloadit.imagemagick.org/MagickStudio/scripts/MagickStudio.cgi](http://transloadit.imagemagick.org/MagickStudio/scripts/MagickStudio.cgi)